# Huggingface AutoTokenizer cannot be referenced when importing Transformers

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am trying to import AutoTokenizer and AutoModelWithLMHead, but I am getting the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'AutoTokenizer' from partially initialized module 'transformers' (most likely due to a circular import)

First, I install transformers: `pip install transformers` then implemented the following code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelWithLMHead

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-base")
model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("t5-base")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For anyone who comes across a problem around circular import, this could be due to the naming convention of your `.py` file. Changing my file name solved the issue as there might be a file in my Python lib folder with similar naming conventions.

Comment: I had the same issue happen to me, but this answer was a bit vague. I was making a quick test and made the mistake of naming my file tokenize.py which upon further reflection and a simple locate indicated this was a pre-existing file in my Python 3.10 lib folder.